# NetBeans needs Javadoc, Eclipse does not?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, javadoc

I just installed NetBeans, and want to try it out. Some context tips (popup javadoc stuff) work, but nothing detailed. It says "Javadoc not found...".

However, I use Eclipse (my current IDE) and it has no problem showing detailed context tips.

Do I HAVE to download the 100+mb zip file to get the javadoc, or can I have Netbeans point to whatever Eclipse is already aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the documentation in Eclipse didn't appear from nowhere - you might have javadoc for the jdk lying around or it's really packaged with Eclipse. In any rate [here](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/how-to-add-javadoc-to-netbeans/) is how you add the JDK javadoc in NetBeans. When I come to think about it I think that simply Eclipse generates the documentation from the JDK sources if they are available and NetBeans probably doesn't.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the huge download. Thanks for the info though.